# How to type text without selecting an element in CodeceptJS?

Tags: android, ios, testing, appium, codeceptjs

Normally I use `I.fillField(elementSelector, text)` to fill the `text` into the field with `elementSelector` xpath or sth.

I have a case where there is only one element (Appium shows no nested elements), that is really six squares one next to the other with a small gap in-between, and if you tap on any of the squares, the first one is focused, and you can type in a 6-digit PIN code to fill all of the squares without tapping each one separately.

Using CodeceptJS I naturally first tried the usual go-to function `I.fillField`, but the keyboard doesn't pop up so the field is not getting filled.

For debugging purposes, I also tried `I.grabElementAndTap` and noticed the keyboard doesn't pop up as well. So my conclusion was, that given an even number of squares, both functions `I.fillField` and `I.grabElementAndTap` must be tapping directly in the middle between squares 3 and 4, and testing manually I confirmed this would not open the keyboard.

Then I decided for a different approach. Using `rect = I.grabElementBoundingRect(elementSelector)` I got the exact screen coordinates where one should click for the keyboard to open:

```js
position = {
    x: parseInt(rect.x) + parseInt(rect.height) / 2
    y: parseInt(rect.y) + parseInt(rect.height) / 2
}
```

Then with

```js
I.touchPerform([{
    action: 'press',
    options: position
}])
```

I succeded in tapping the element so the keyboard is opened.

#### How do I type text now just using the keyboard (without getting x,y coordinates of every digit on the keyboard and `touchPerform` again)?

If I use `I.fillField` now, I must give the `elementSelector` as the first parameter, and that closes the keyboard.

Is there a way to type using opened keyboard without selecting anything?

Or is there a way for `touchPerform` to type text as well?

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you can always use:

```
I.sendDeviceKeyEvent(7)
```

Where event "7" would send a "0" key. Here is the list of all [Key Events](https://gist.github.com/arjunv/2bbcca9a1a1c127749f8dcb6d36fb0bc).

For iOS, use:

```
I.tap('~0')
```

this would tap on the "0" key on the keyboard, or just change the key to any other key you need instead of 0.